# How do I print all values of a dictionary in order?

Tags: python, dictionary, printing

I am a rookie. Collectively, I have about two weeks of experience with any sort of computer code.

I created a dictionary with some baseball player names, their batting order, and the position they play. I'm trying to get it to print out in columns with "order", "name", and "position" as headings, with the order numbers, positions, and names under those. Think spreadsheet kind of layout (stackoverflow won't let me format the way I want to in here).

order     name         position
1         A Baddoo     LF
2         J Schoop     1B
3         R Grossman   DH

[I'm new here, so apparently you have to click the link to see what I wrote. Dodgy, I know...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFtK2.png)

As you can see, I have tried 257 times to get this thing to work. I've consulted the google, a python book, and other sources to no avail.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include any relevant information [as text directly into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), do not link or embed external images of source code or data. Images make it difficult to efficiently assist you as they cannot be copied and offer poor usability as they cannot be searched. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15497888)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code

```
for order in lineup["order"]:
    order -= 1
    position = lineup["position"][order]
    name = lineup["name"][order ]
    print(order + 1, name, position)
```

Your Dictionary consists of 3 lists - if you want entry 0 you will have to access entry 0 in each list separately.

This would be an easier way to use a dictionary

```
players = {1: ["LF", "A Baddoo"],
           2: ["1B", "J Schoop"]}
for player in players:
    print(players[player])
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah, that works when I use it in Spyder and it looks exactly like what I envisioned, but I get an error when I run that in a Jupyter notebook, which is what we're using for class. Weird. It says the int object is not callable in that first line you provided.

Comment: That is a weird error to be called by the code. I changed the code a bit - try the new one, if the error keeps happening you could rename "order" to something else. For more information on the error read this: https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-typeerror-int-object-is-not-callable/

Answer (score 0):

`Pandas` is good for creating tables as you describe what you are trying to do. You can convert a dictionary into a a dataframe/table. The only catch here is the number of rows need to be the same length, which in this case it is not. The columns `order`, `position`, `name` all have 9 items in the list, while `pitcher` only has 1. So what we can do is pull out the `pitcher` key using `pop`. This will leave you with a dictionary with just those 3 column names mentioned above, and then a list with your 1 item for `pitcher`.

```
import pandas as pd

lineup = {'order': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
          'position': ['LF', '1B', 'RF','DH','3B','SS','2B','C','CF'],
          'name': ['A Baddoo','J Schoop','R Grossman','M Cabrera','J Candelario', 'H Castro','W Castro','D Garneau','D Hill'],
          'pitcher':['Matt Manning']}


pitching = lineup.pop('pitcher')
starting_lineup = pd.DataFrame(lineup)

print("Today's Detroit Tigers starting lineup is: \n", starting_lineup.to_string(index=False), "\nPitcher: ", pitching[0])
```

**Output:**

```
Today's Detriot Tigers starting lineup is: 
  order position         name
     1       LF     A Baddoo
     2       1B     J Schoop
     3       RF   R Grossman
     4       DH    M Cabrera
     5       3B J Candelario
     6       SS     H Castro
     7       2B     W Castro
     8        C    D Garneau
     9       CF       D Hill 
Pitcher:  Matt Manning
```